# Removing mulitple extensions in chrome

Tags: bash

I need to remove multiple chrome extensions from several hundred devices. I have a script that will see if a certain extension exists and if it does then deletes the Default folder. How can I add multiple extensions to my script so that if any of these extensions exist the Default folder is deleted? The script currently looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

currentUser=`ls -l /dev/console | awk '{print $3}'`

if [ -d "/Users/$currentUser/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/omghfjlpggmjjaagoclmmobgdodcjboh" ]; then
rm -rf "/Users/$currentUser/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default" && killall "Google Chrome"  && echo "<result>Delete Browsec</result>"
else
echo "<result>No</result>"
fi
```

Comment: What is the "currentUser" supposed to be? The user who's running the script? The one who is currently logged in? Your command will print the owner of `/dev/console`, why is that relevant? What operating systems does this need to run on? As far as I know, only OSX and presumably iOS uses `/Users`. What are the extension names you want to remove?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various minor issues and things I don't understand in your script which I asked about in my comment. In the meantime, without touching anything else in your script, you could just provide a list of extension names as an array:

```
#!/bin/bash

currentUser=`ls -l /dev/console | awk '{print $3}'`
exts=("omghfjlpggmjjaagoclmmobgdodcjboh" "foofoobarbar" "barbarfofo")

for extension in "${exts[@]}";
do
    if [ -d "/Users/$currentUser/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/$extension" ]; then
        rm -rf "/Users/$currentUser/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default" && killall "Google Chrome"  && echo "<result>Delete Browsec</result>"
    else
        echo "<result>No</result>"
    fi
done
```

I don't know what the target OSs are but I must point out that this is not portable at *all* and will fail on any Linux for example.

Comment: I work in a school environment supporting and managing Macs. This script is run as an Extension Attribute from JAMF. I should have been clear about that. The script as it is runs fine on Mac and in the JAMF console I just didn't know how to implement the array.

Comment: @bubishi ah, fair enough then. I don't know OSX and your way of getting the user makes no sense to me. If you're sure it's fine, then this should work. By the way, if this answer solves your issue please take a minute and click the check mark under the vote count to the left, this will [signify to everyone](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that your issue's been resolved.

Comment: Could the same result be achieved using case?

Comment: @bubishi well, yes, but why would you want to? It would be much harder to write for one thing. And it wouldn't improve anything, you'd still need to iterate all of them. All you would do is make your script longer. `case` is better for when you have one variable to check and want to see which of multiple patterns it matches. Here, you have many variables and want to remove any and all instances of them. In any case, to get a better answer, please [edit] your question and include the list of extensins you want to remove. It can probably be done in a single line with brace expansion.